# Qual a diferença entra map() e mapSpread() Eloquent Collection's

Tags: php, laravel-eloquent

Eu estou a um tempo com o eloquent, mas já li a documentação e não consegui entender a diferença entre o método `map()` e `mapSpread()`, existe outros métodos com 'Spread' no nome, alguém teria um exemplo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [`Collection::map(callable $callback): Collection`](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_map)

> Run a map over each of the items.

O método `map` irá iterar sobre cada item do array, aplicando o `$callback` e retornando um novo valor para o item, colocando cada um dos valores gerados pelo `$callback` em uma nova `Collection` e retornando esta `Collection`.

Exemplo de `Collection` para uso com `map`:

```
Collection([item1, item2, ...])
```

O `Collection::map` pode ser comparado ao `Array.map` do JavaScript.

## [`Collection::mapSpread(callable $callback): Collection`](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_mapSpread)

> Run a map over each nested chunk of items.

O `mapSpread` fara basicamente a mesma coisa, mas com uma diferença, ele espera trabalhar em cima de uma `Collection` de dois níveis, como um `array` de `array`s e, ao invés de aplicar o `$callback` em cada filho direto (de primeiro nível), ele abrirá (em inglês *spread*) cada um dos filhos diretos, que são do tipo `Collection`, e aplicará o `$callback` em cada um dos filhos diretos de cada `Collection` que for aberta. Novamente o valor retornado por cada execução do `$callback` será armazenado em uma nova `Collection` que será retornada ao final da execução do método.

Exemplo de `Collection` para uso com `mapSpread`:

```
Collection([
    Collection([item1, item2, ...])
    Collection([item1, item2, ...])
    Collection([item1, item2, ...])
    Collection([item1, item2, ...])
    Collection([...])
    ...
])
```

O `Collection::mapSpread` pode ser comparado ao `Array.flatMap` do JavaScript.